# How to pick random numbers from pot with some winning numbers?

Tags: php, random

i am trying to make a very simple game where i have 7 positions which are all hidden and within those there a 3 winning positions.  I can pick randomly 3 times. I need to display whether the pick is a winning or not after every pick and store the result in a base.

Currently my thought where to generate an array of winning numbers on the first pick and then pick random number and check if it is in the winning array.

But i have a feeling that there is much more efficient way to do so.

Would appreciate if you would use PHP for coding examples, but pseudo code will do as-well.

**EDIT**
i am looking for the way to solve this without populating array with winning positions. maybe there is a way to do this with weights or probability percents.

Something like on first pick i have 3/7*100 percent chance to win. save result to base.
on second pick i have either 3/6*100 or 2/6*100 percent chance to win based weather i won in previous pick which i get from base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised answer: this example does not require you to store the complete state of the game in a variable; instead, you just need to store the try count and won count:

```
$won = 0;
for($try = 0; $try < 3; $try++) {
    $slots = array_fill(0, 7 - $try, 0);  // blank slots
    $lucky = array_fill(0, 3 - $won, 1);  // lucky slots
    $pot = array_replace($slots, $lucky); // make some of the slots lucky
    $win = $pot[array_rand($pot)];        // randomly pick a slot
    $won += $win == 1;                    // update won count
    echo sprintf("Try %d: win=%d, total wins=%d\n", $try + 1, $win, $won);
}
```

Original answer:

```
$pot = array(               // pot is (an associative) array; 0 = blank, 1 = win
    "pos_1" => 0,
    "pos_2" => 0,
    "pos_3" => 0,
    "pos_4" => 0,
    "pos_5" => 0,
    "pos_6" => 0,
    "pos_7" => 0
);
$win = array_rand($pot, 3); // picks three indexes from the pot randomly
foreach($win as $w) {
    $pot[$w] = 1;           // set winning indicator
}
print_r($pot);
```

Output: array containing state of the pots.

```
Array
(
    [pos_1] => 0
    [pos_2] => 1
    [pos_3] => 0
    [pos_4] => 1
    [pos_5] => 1
    [pos_6] => 0
    [pos_7] => 0
)
```

Comment: this means i need to store the shuffled array in base or session and this is the thing i want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can just save the positions of the winning numbers. This way you can always check their values using the `[]` operator for arrays. After all, you just pick the positions and not the numbers.

**Update:**
This way you even don't need to hide numbers. It's quite possible to have some more abstract "winning things" - characters, words, structures. However, it is important that you do not alter your array of hidden "things" in any way or at least update the stored winning positions accordingly if they stay the same. If that's not the case you'd naturally need to update the saved winning positions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$arr = array(true, true, false, false, false, false, false);
shuffle($arr);

function pick($arr, $index) {
    return isset($arr[$index]) && $arr[$index] === true;
}

var_dump($arr);
var_dump(pick($arr, 3));
var_dump(pick($arr, 5));
var_dump(pick($arr, 1));
```

Comment: this means i need to store the shuffled array in base or session and this is the thing i want to avoid.